# How can I access ProjectionMatrix in three.js directly?

Tags: three.js, projection-matrix

How can I access the perspective camera's projection matrix directly and change one or more of the 16 values?

I tried the code bellow with and without .updateProjectionMatrix() and it doesn't work, probably it is overiden by an internal function:

```
cameraPersp.projectionMatrix.elements.set = 
(a,b,c,d,
e,f,g,h,
i,j,k,l,
m,n,o,p);

cameraPersp.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Also, I have no idea if it can be multiplied, added etc using .set  (lack of documentation) -it doesn't raise an error though.

Comment: `camera.projectionMatrix`? The single elements are kept inside the `.elements` property (an array) of a matrix object.

Comment: I tried the code bellow with and without .updateProjectionMatrix() and it doesn't work, probably it is overiden by an internal function:
cameraPersp.projectionMatrix.elements.set = 
 (a,b,c,d,
  e,f,g,h,
  i,j,k,l,
  m,n,o,p);

    cameraPersp.updateProjectionMatrix();

Also, I don't have any idea if it can be multiplied, added etc using .set  (lack of documentation)

Comment: If you call `.updateProjectionMatrix()`, the `projectionMatrix` is calculated from scratch. This will overwrite any values you've manually set before. The `projectionMatrix` itself is an instance of `Matrix4`: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Matrix4

Comment: Yes, I just found out.  It works, without using "elements", "=" and "updateProjectionMatrix()" -see update above. 
How can I change a single matrix value directly?

Comment: @user5515 `camera.projectionMatrix.elements[ 0 ] = 1;`

Comment: Yes, apparently that works, thanks. The irony is I tried that a while ago but it didn't work as I wrote it as a number implying row-column order like [31] instead of array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to set a given matrix to custom float values, directly:

```
cameraPersp.projectionMatrix.set 
(a,b,c,d,
e,f,g,h,
i,j,k,l,
m,n,o,p);
```

To change a single matrix value directly:

```
cameraPersp.projectionMatrix.elements[n] = yourfloatvalue;
```

In both cases, updateProjectionMatrix() should NOT be called.